# Scala: Remove elements from Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Vector and want to remove elements from the Vector. How can I do it in Scala?My input is a Vector[2.0, 3.0, 0.3, 1.0, 4.0] -->Vector[Double] and I want a Vector[2.0, 0.3, 4.0] as output, so I want to remove the element with the index 1 and 3 from my input Vector...

```
def removeElementFromVector(input: Vector) = {   
  val inputAsArray = input.toArray

  inputAsArray

  // ...
  val reducedInputAsVector = inputAsArray.toVector 
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say that you want to remove an element how does that concretely happen ? Can you give an example input and output about what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use filter to achieve it, but we need to add index to remove element at an index:

Ex: Your vector (scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Double]):

```
scala> val v1 = val v1 = Vector(2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 4.4)

Output: Vector(2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 4.4)
```

Now, we will remove element at index 2:

```
scala> var indexRemove=2

scala> val v2 = v1.zipWithIndex.filter(x => x._2!=indexRemove).map(x=>x._1).toVector
Output: Vector(2.2, 3.3, 5.5, 6.6, 4.4)
```

Now, we will remove element at index 3

```
scala> var indexRemove=3
scala> val v2 = v1.zipWithIndex.filter(x => x._2!=indexRemove).map(x=>x._1).toVector
Output: Vector(2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 6.6, 4.4)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx but it's not working, maybe becaus I am using an " org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector "

Comment: That's not gonna remove the thing at index 2, it's gonna remove all things that are equal to the thing at index 2. (indexOf will give the index of the first thing to equal x) You could do v1.diff List(v1(N)) to delete only a single instance of the Nth item. If you want to specifically delete the Nth item you need to do v1.slice(0, N) ++ v1.slice(N+1, v1.size). Or v1.zip(0 to v1.size).filterNot(_._2 == N).map(_._1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method to remove them.

```
> val reducedInputVector = input.filter(x => !(Array(1,3) contains input.indexOf(x)))
reducedInputVector: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Double] = Vector(2.0, 0.3, 4.0)
```

Comment: This answer isn't correct nor does it make sense. Can you review it please ?

Comment: @eliasah I have updated the code now. Can you please check if this is fine? I did not understand why it was not correct. Was it because I was being too blunt?

Answer (score 0):

My input is: Vector[2.0, 3.0, 0.3, 1.0, 4.0] -->Vector[Double] and I want a Vector[2.0, 3.0, 0.3, 4.0] as output, so I want to remove the element with the index 1 and 3 from my input Vector. Sry for my question was not clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with apply:

```
val vec1 = Vector(2.0,3.0,0.3,1.0, 4.0)
val vec2 = Vectors.dense(vec1.apply(0), vec1.apply(1),vec1.apply(2), vec1.apply(4))
```

the output is

```
vec1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Double] = Vector(2.0, 3.0, 0.3, 1.0, 4.0)
vec2: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [2.0,3.0,0.3,4.0]
```

Comment: Vectors.dense is not part of the Scala standard library, vec2 has a different datatype than vec1. Also, writing `vec1.apply(0)` is unnecessarily verbose, since you can simply write `vec1(0)`.

Comment: In your question and comments you've repeatedly stated that you want to "remove the element with the index 1 and 3" but what you've done is remove only the element at index 3 in a very inefficient manner.  Your question and your solution make no sense.  If your `Vector` had 247 elements and you wanted to remove the one at index 9, is that how you'd do it?

Comment: my input is a Vector of the type "org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector".

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleteItem[A](row: Vector[A], item: Int): Vector[A] = {
  val (a,b) = row.splitAt(item)
  if (b!=Nil) a ++ b.tail else a
}
```